# Getting weird output from sorting string object arrays (code provided)?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, user-input

Note: not using arraylist, hashset, set, or importing any other packages other than Scanner.

```
public static String sorting(){
for (int i = 0; i < pigArray.length; i++){
    for (int k = i + 1; k <pigArray.length; k++){

        if(pigArray[k].getName().trim().compareTo(pigArray[i].getName().trim())< 0){
        String temp = pigArray[i].getName();
        pigArray[i].setName( pigArray[k].getName );
        pigrray[k].setName(temp);
        }
        }
    }
}

String sorted = "";

for (int m = 0; m < pigArray.length; m++){

    sorted = sorted + "\n" + pigArray[m].getSortedName();     
}

return sorted;
}
```

Basically what happens to my code is if every input the user inputs are out of order (and I do mean every single one of them), the program sorts them fine.

Example (not actual input but for description): 
 input: e, c,b,a  output: a, b, c, d

However if even one of them is in the correct spot, the program replace it with null.

Example:
  input: a, e, d, c   output: null, c, d, e

I have no idea why that is happening. Number of inputs doesn't matter.

Any tips are appreciated. Thank you.

Edit:

```
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
    }

public String getSortedName() {
    return name;
   }
```

Comment: I think in the if statement you only populate the array if the next letter is "smaller" than the previous and so in a case which the next letter is "larger" than the previous that position of the array stays null.

Comment: To elthumb: Any tips on how I should fix this problem? with another elseif statement? and pigarray is my object array that stores input of the pig names.

Comment: Yes, with an elseif statement and then an else statement to cover the case that previous and next are the same.

Comment: I put that in now . Thank you. But what should I put inside each case?  compareTo == 0 and compareTo >0 ? Can you give me  some tips on that? If you would like, you can put that (or part of it) in the answer and I ll upvote you.

Comment: Post the entire class of whatever kind of object is in `pigArray`, not just part of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error might lie in your implemenation of pigArray.

I changed your code so that pigArray is just a `String` array and it sorted the values just fine for me.

```
public class Test {
     private static String[] pigArray;

public static String sorting(){
    pigArray = new String[]{"a", "e", "d", "c"};

    for (int i = 0; i < pigArray.length; i++){
        for (int k = i + 1; k <pigArray.length; k++){

            if(pigArray[k].trim().compareTo(pigArray[i].trim())< 0){
            String temp = pigArray[i];
            pigArray[i]=( pigArray[k] );
            pigArray[k]=(temp);
            }
            }
        }

    String sorted = "";

    for (int m = 0; m < pigArray.length; m++){

        sorted = sorted + "\n" + pigArray[m];     
    }

    return sorted;
    }

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.print(Test.sorting());
}
}
```

This returned "acde" as expected.

Comment: That would work but i need setter and getter because i need to call my class method to obtain the names stored in the object array

Comment: My point is that I think your getter/setters or `getSortedName` method must not be working properly because it works otherwise

Comment: ok I updated my code on that. I thought that was the way it's suppose to work, so I didn't post that part. Sorry about that.

Comment: hmm I don't see anything directly wrong with that. Try stepping through your calls and making sure that the input you are passing in is properly instantiated. What's the difference between `getName()` and `getSortedName()`

Comment: getName() method returns the string depending on pigArray[]. I can assure you that part of the code does work and output the correct name (because if not, then rest of my code won't work) Only this part regarding sorting is giving me problems.

Comment: well I'm out of ideas then. Make a test and use `asserts` to make sure that the pigarray is properly populated before you call `sorting()` and then step through until something goes wrong. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(pigArray[k].getName().trim().compareTo(pigArray[i].getName().trim())< 0){
    String temp = pigArray[i].getName();
    pigArray[i].setName( pigArray[k].getName );
    pigrray[k].setName(temp);
    }
 elseif(pigArray[k].getName().trim().compareTo(pigArray[i].getName().trim())> 0){
    String temp = pigArray[k].getName();
    pigArray[k].setName( pigArray[i].getName );
    pigrray[i].setName(temp);
    }
 else
    pigArray[i].setName( pigArray[i].getName );`
```

i think that should work, i don't the rest of your code though. hope it helps.

Comment: so I still seem to have a bit of problem: when i enter b, c, d the program outputs d, d, c

Comment: What about your `getSortedName` ? It does something else? Maybe it would be helpful if you posted all of your code.

Comment: Updated. Please tell me if I need to add more.

Comment: Yes, put all of it up so i can run it and not guessing every time.

Comment: I think that's everything though. The rest of the code is very long and probably fill a lot of space on this page. Also I added your code in into the for loop.

Comment: if you are still there . I tried some more inputs and fixed some parts of my code. Now it is this: input: b, d, c outpUt: c, c, d

Comment: What is `pigArray[i].setName( pigArray[i].getName );` supposed to achieve?